# Ionic 4.2.1 Modal Memory Leak

Tags: ios, angular, ionic-framework, memory-leaks, modal-dialog

I have been developing a kiosk app, with Ionic, for use on 12.9" iPad Pros. With these up and running for a few weeks, I noticed animation performance (specifically with an `<ion-slides>` element) degrading and traced it back to a memory leak. I'm using two modals in this app. When either modal is dismissed, if I force garbage collection then look at the memory allocation timeline and memory snapshots in the Chrome developer tools I can see the modals sitting there as detached DOM elements. Every time the modal is closed and re-opened the allocated memory gets a tiny bit larger. One of these modals is fairly complex with a dynamic src `<video>` element and associated playback control buttons but the other is pretty simple, consisting only of a few text elements pulled from json data using *ngFor.

Normally, this memory leak wouldn't be big enough to worry about. Your typical user would never open and close the modals enough to cause problems on a reasonable timeframe. But, these iPads are in a public space and receive hundreds of users to only this app every day. Depending on how busy we are, it is taking roughly a week of use before the memory leaks cause noticeable issues. They are running this in Single App Mode. So to restart them, I have to unlock the kiosk enclosure, retrieve the iPads, connect them to Configurator on my computer, restart them, and re-install them in the enclosure. Not exactly something I want to be doing every few days if I can avoid it.

I've found a few other posts, here and on GitHub, on similar issues but none with any real answers. Is there any way to ensure these modals are properly destroyed when they are dismissed?

Ionic is not my typical development platform. I normally work in React but someone decided we had to use iPads for this despite all of us telling them it was a terrible idea. So, it's also entirely possible I'm a moron and there's something obvious I'm missing here.

Thanks!

The code for the simpler one is...

**JS**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams, Events, ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { CreditsProvider } from '../../providers/credits/credits';

/**
 * Generated class for the CreditsModalPage page.
 *
 * See https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
 * Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

@Component({
  selector: 'page-credits-modal',
  templateUrl: 'credits-modal.html',
})
export class CreditsModalPage {
  public games = [];
  public ahStaff = [];
  public playCapture = [];

  constructor(private creditsProvider: CreditsProvider, public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public events: Events, private viewCtrl: ViewController) {
    events.subscribe('timeout', (state) => {
      if (state === 'home') {
        this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
      }
    })
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.creditsProvider.getCredits().subscribe((response) => {
      this.games = response.games;
      this.ahStaff = response.ahStaff;
      this.playCapture = response.playCapture;

      //update all staff to not show easter egg
      this.ahStaff.forEach(staff => {
        staff.showNickname = false;
      });
    });
  }

  /*
  * If the staff member has a nickname, toggle the easter egg on and off
  */
  toggleEasterEgg(index) {
    if(this.ahStaff[index].nickname !== null){//if they have a nickname
      //toggle the easter egg
      this.ahStaff[index].showNickname = !this.ahStaff[index].showNickname;
    }
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!--
  Generated template for the CreditsModalPage page.

  See http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
  Ionic pages and navigation.
-->
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar color="dark">
    <ion-title>Credits</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content padding class="creditsContent">
  <h1>Staff</h1>
  <div class="credit" *ngFor="let staff of ahStaff; let i = index">
    <p (click)="toggleEasterEgg(i)" >{{staff.role + ' - '}}<span [ngClass]="{'glitch': staff.showNickname}" [attr.data-text]="staff.nickname">{{staff.showNickname ? staff.nickname : staff.name}}</span></p>
  </div>
  <h1>Play Capture</h1>
  <div class="credit" *ngFor="let player of playCapture">
    <p>{{player}}</p>
  </div>
  <h1>Games</h1>
  <div class="credit" *ngFor="let game of games">
    <h2>{{game.name}}</h2>
    <p *ngIf="game.year !== null">{{"Year Published - " + game.year}}</p>
    <p *ngIf="game.developer !== null">{{"Developer - " + game.developer}}</p>
    <p *ngIf="game.publisher !== null">{{"Publisher - " + game.publisher}}</p>
    <p *ngIf="game.note !== null">{{game.note}}</p>
  </div>

</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to unsubscribe every subscription that will never be completed.

```
private onTimeout = (state) => {
    if (state === 'home') {
      this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
    };
}

ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.events.subscribe('timeout', onTimeout);
}

ionViewWillLeave() {
    this.events.unsubscribe('timeout', onTimeout);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Gilsdav I knew there had to be at least one obvious thing I missed. Unfortunately, it seems that wasn't the full problem. With those unsubscribed in ionViewWillLeave I still have DOM nodes detached. I also have a simpler modal, just yes and no buttons that dismiss the modal and pass which it was to onDidDismiss that shows the same problem.

Comment: Is there same issue if you use `this.modalCtrl.dismiss()` instead of `this.viewCtrl.dismiss()` ?

Comment: No luck there. `this.modalCtrl.dismiss()` throws a "property dismiss does not exist on type ModalController" error but if I do `let creditsModal = this.modalController.create(CreditsModalPage);` then `creditsModal.dismiss()` the leak is still there. Same if I only use the navBar close button to dismiss. Heap, Documents, and listeners all drop on GC but no change in DOM nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for you help @Gilsdav. But, it looks like this is a problem with Ionic itself. I did what I should have done in the beginning and went straight to the Ionic Modal documentation [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/modal/ModalController/) and looked for memory leaks with the example that's there. Sure enough, I'm seeing exactly the same behavior. [Ionic Docs Performance Timeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBOGq.png). The listeners, JS Heap, and Documents all get cleaned up on garbage collection but DOM nodes keep climbing. Looking at the heap snapshots, I see the full contents of the modal as detached DOM elements, exactly as I did with my own code.

In 99+% percent of use cases this leak is small enough it would not be a huge issue. So, I wouldn't consider this a huge problem with Ionic. But, I need to be able to have this run for months at a time without problems. So, it looks like I'll either be finding a way to reformat this to not use modals or will have to find a way to reboot the iPads nightly.

**Update!!!**

So in case anyone else needs a solution to this problem, here's what I've ended up doing. I'm not sure if it's the correct way, but it seems to be working.

One of the problem modals was a timeout prompt that just periodically makes sure someone is still there. If no one responds it just resets the app to the main view. When this modal is dismissed, I've simply called `window.location.reload()` to reload the app. It definitely does not look pretty when testing in Chrome but is actually pretty seamless when running on the device.

Looking at the javascript allocations on the actual device, through the Safari Developer Tools, I can see the live size steadily increasing as I open and close modals. But, as soon as that timeout modal dismisses and it reloads, it goes right back to the original level.